# TableView does not load full array due to size

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift2

I am having an array having 22 entered. Each cell size of table view 80 in height. I checked the full tableview is of 600*600 size. So I can only load 600/80  = 7 cell.

So I am looking to load the full content of the array to the table view.So that user scroll down the content will be loaded.
when i load the table view in simulator i can see only 7 cells. scroll is locked and i can not access more records.

Please suggest how can I achieve this??  I hope I can explain this time better

```
class RestaurentTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var restaurantNames = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H",
"I", "J", "K", "L", "M",
    "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R",
    "S", "T", "U"] override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //self.tableHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(restaurantNames.count * 80)

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return restaurantNames.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RestaurantTableViewCell


cell.nameLabel.text = restaurantNames[indexPath.row]
cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: restaurantImages[indexPath.row])
        cell.locationLabel.text = restaurantLocations[indexPath.row]
        cell.typeLabel.text = restaurantTypes[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: Please elaborate on what you have tried and post your code so far.

Comment: @Ashish I'm not sure what you're asking ; it either looks like a question about the under-the-hood code, or a question about your confusion of cell reusability, or maybe a slight error in your code that displays unexpected behaviour. Either way, could you show us all the relevant code? Your tableview methods in your viewcontroller would be a good start, and how you fill your data array. You can flag me (@Zil) once you've donne that, I'll come here and look again

Comment: @Zil i kept the code also. I m new here how to flag someone i don't know

Comment: It all looks good at first glance. And your problem is that you can't scroll to see new content, right? or that you CAN scroll but have empty cells?

Comment: Are you sure you are scrolling correctly in the simulator? You have to click-scroll - regular scrolling doesn't work.

Comment: @Zil I can not scroll more than that. Only it locks the view there.

Comment: @Greg  Yes i tried click scroll also. But scrolling is working as first view is not holding all seven names.

Comment: I have added a small project at the below location     you can see only " L" is loaded. can't i have all in one.. https://www.dropbox.com/s/o7w9zlyxwa6mul7/TestTable.zip?dl=0

Comment: @matthew I added my project.. Just want that scroll should cover all the items of the array. But it stuck at L on the display

Comment: Please reply as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by that question. What you are asking for happens automatically. Refer to the documentation of UITableView, and the various delegate methods in UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource.

Do you have any reason why you believe scrolling wouldn't work?

Comment: it is like my array has     var restaurantNames = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H",
    "I", "J", "K", "L", "M",
        "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R",
        "S", "T", "U"] and when i load the application it loads the table it till H. I was expecting to load all the data. My Cell height is 80. So it loads 7 full and 8th half. Let me know if still i am not making sense I will try to share my code.